# Google Cloud Shell VM not starting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I have a Google Cloud project with billing enabled but consuming no resources at the moment. I would like to deploy the project with Google Cloud Shell but I cannot get the shell to start. I see a "Provisioning your Google Cloud Shell machine" message which lasts a few minutes, before I get a random error, typically a 502.

I have tried different browsers, clearing the cache, incognito mode and the Google Cloud app on my phone. I have also disabled all security on my router and added console.cloud.google.com to my allowed list. I have even tried on my cellular network.

Comment: It sounds like an error on Google side. Try again later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are experiencing issues while starting Google Cloud Shell and receiving 502 error, there are few troubleshooting steps you can try.

In the Cloud Shell Menu, you can select **Restart** and a pop-up dialog will ask for confirmation on **Restart Cloud Shell.** After this, a new VM shall be provisioned for you to use.

[image]

1. You can also do safe mode to login as root and check any problem in your .bashrc or .tmux.conf files, to see documentation click [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#safe_mode).
2. After doing safe mode, if necessary, you can also get a completely new cloud shell state by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell#reset).

Also you can try to set up **Google Cloud SDK** on your computer and use your terminal/shell. Switch to Ephemeral Mode. Please notice that it is a fresh env and does not maintain any persistent state between sessions.

For more information you can check this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell). If the issue still persists, kindly contact [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/contact).

Comment: Thanks. Ephemeral mode with safe mode works, which is welcome progress.

Comment: Now after starting in safe mode I can get back to the default shell. Even further progress!

Comment: Still only works in ephemeral mode though.